# Why this error in mysql making a table?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I just want a make table like below.

```
create table android_data ( 
    index int unsigned primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    phone int not null, 
    sensorID int not null, 
    press int not null, 
    temp int not null, 
    accel int not null, 
    gps_lat double not null, 
    gps_lng double not null, 
    time timestamp default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp
    )engine=innodb;
```

But I got an error in

```
 index int unsigned primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
        phone int not null,
```

I cant understand Why this is wrong with manual....

What should I do to make right table??

Comment: hmmmm.... i think "id" is better than "index".... index is a reserved word in mysql

Comment: you must put reserved Keywords in backticks like ``index`` to use them as fieldname

Answer (score 1):

Index is a reserved keyword in MySQL.  If you must name your primary key `index` you should put it in backticks:

```
create table android_data ( 
    `index` int unsigned primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
     ...
)
```

But ideally you should avoid naming tables and columns using MySQL keywords for the very reason you have already seen.

[**MySQL keywords**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)